# Why is n not an integer?

Tags: list, typeerror

```
months=["Jan","Feb","March","April"]
temp =[]

for n in months:
    temp = int(input("please enter a number for ",months[n]))
```

This gives an error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

I don't understand this. Please help.

Comment: Could you please add which language is this?

Comment: Since you are using `in` and you are iterating over an array of strings, n is an string, not an integer.

Comment: If this is Python, then you need to go back to a good tutorial and reread it.

Comment: do you know one cause even people here cant answer it

Comment: People here are so helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over a list of strings `months`, so `n` is already a string. In every iteration of the `for` loop, `n` is equal to the next item in `months`.

```
months=["Jan","Feb","March","April"]
temp =[]

for month in months:
    temp.append(int(input("please enter a number for " + month)))
```

Comment: TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2 ?

Comment: `input` expects one argument but you gave it two. As my example shows, you can concatenate `month` (a string) to the other string "please enter a number for " to get one final string which is sent as one argument to `input`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @AlanRobinson upto my knowledge it should not be  



temp = int(input("please enter a number for ",month)) 
as you r trying to type cast an array of type string to int but in unmanered way
```

Comment: @AlanRobinson try this - system.out.println("please enter a number for ", +month)